# Computing excess returns

Tags: python, pandas, finance

I would like to compute the excess returns of dataframe of stock returns, where excess returns are defined as the difference between the stock returns and the market, where market it represented by the ticker SPY. Below is min-example

```
dict0 = {'date': [1/1/2020,1/1/2020,1/1/2020,1/2/2020,1/2/2020,1/2/2020,,1/3/2020,1/3/2020,1/3/2020], 'ticker': ['SPY','AAPL','SPY','AAPL', 'MSFT','SPY','AAPL','MSFT'], 'returns': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)### 
df.set_index(['date','ticker'])
```

The goal is to create excess returns (that is, everything in excess of the market, which is equal to the ticker SPY)

```
df['excess_returns']= [0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of code where you do set_index, you should assign the dataframe back to itself or do it inplace.
Remaining you can do it as follows:

```
def func(row):
    date, asset = row.name
    return df.loc[(date, asset), 'returns'] - df.loc[(date, 'SPY'), 'returns']



dict0 = {'date': ['1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/2/2020',
                  '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/3/2020'],
         'ticker': ['SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'],
         'returns': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)  ###
df = df.set_index(['date', 'ticker'])
df['excess_returns'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: This is excellent and very elegant!!! Thank you so much, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the vectorized solution:

**One Liner**

```
df['excess_returns'] = df.returns - df.groupby('date').returns.transform('first')
```

**Complete Solution**

```
dict0 = {'date': ['1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/1/2020', '1/2/2020', '1/2/2020',
                  '1/2/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/3/2020', '1/3/2020'],
         'ticker': ['SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT', 'SPY', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'],
         'returns': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict0)

## Firstly I would convert date to datetime type, if required
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['excess_returns'] = df.returns - df.groupby('date').returns.transform('first')

## by any means if I require to set the index to date and ticker
df = df.set_index(['date', 'ticker']) ## Only if required

df
```

**Output**

```
                    returns excess_returns
date        ticker      
2020-01-01  SPY     1       0
            AAPL    2       1
            MSFT    3       2
2020-02-01  SPY     4       0
            AAPL    5       1
            MSFT    6       2
2020-03-01  SPY     7       0
            AAPL    8       1
            MSFT    9       2
```